# Is there a way to factor: $x^2 - 6xy + y^2$?

Tags: polynomials, factoring

Is there a way to factor $x^2 - 6xy + y^2$? I know the result, if there is one, would be irrational. Also, for cases like this where the result would include irrational terms like $\sqrt{2}$, is there a good guide out there for how to perform such factorizations?

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you  so much :)

Comment: "I know the result" , what is then the question ?

Comment: @Peter Should read "I know that a factorization is either irrational or does not exist"

Comment: @Peter, please read the full thing; I was merely stating that I knew a property of the result (if one exists), not that I knew what the result is

Comment: The factorization of $x^2+pxy+qy^2$ is closely related to the roots of the quadratic $x^2+px+q$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done as part of diagonalizing the form (over the rationals), which is just  completing the square.  The identity below says
$$  (x-3y)^2 - 8 y^2  = x^2 - 6xy + y^2  $$
This is the same as a difference of squares,
$$  (x-3y)^2 - (\sqrt8 \;y)^2  = x^2 - 6xy + y^2  $$
or
$$  (x - 3y + \sqrt 8  y ) (x - 3y - \sqrt 8  y )   $$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 & 0 \\ 
 - 3 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 8 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 &  - 3 \\ 
0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 &  - 3 \\ 
 - 3 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

For three variables, this works only when the discriminant is zero.
I ran a search for such  things   and chose
$$  3 x^2 + 8y^2 + 10 z^2 +6yz + 7zx -5 xy$$

This one includes fractions,

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 5 }{ 6 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 7 }{ 6 }  & 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
6 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 71 }{ 6 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 5 }{ 6 }  &  \frac{ 7 }{ 6 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
6 &  - 5 & 7 \\ 
 - 5 & 16 & 6 \\ 
7 & 6 & 20 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Dividing the second an fourth matrix by $2$   shows
$$  3 \left( x - \frac{5y}{6} +  \frac{7z}{6} \right)^2  + \frac{71}{12} ( y+z)^2 =   3 x^2 + 8y^2 + 10 z^2 +6yz + 7zx -5 xy $$

To finish, write as a difference of squares, which means absorbing $\sqrt 3$ into the first thing squared, then $ i \sqrt{\frac{71}{12}}$  into the second.  The $i$ is necessary because we have a plus sign rather than a minus.

On the other hand,   that is not necessary for finding the (real) points where the form is zero. All that requires is $  x - \frac{5y}{6} +  \frac{7z}{6}  =0   $   and $y+z = 0,$  the result being the line through the origin  where $z = -y$   and $x = 2y.$  This is the line through the origin and through $(2,1,-1)$